SwiftUI，When the .sheet pops up, the @State var is abnormally cleared
In the following code,
I expected the following result: When the "Manage" button is clicked, the sheet that pops up will display the contents of the "tags" array ["test1", "test2", "test3"].
However, the actual result is that when the "Manage" button is clicked, the sheet that pops up is blank and the contents of the "tags" array are cleared.
I found that when I removed the Form, it worked as expected.
However, when I added the Form, the problem occurred.
Or, when I don't use removeAll in TagView, this problem also doesn't occur.
Could you tell me why this is happening?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingTagManagement = false
    @State private var tags: [String] = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            VStack() {
                // Selected Tags
                ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                    TagView(tag: tag) {
                        tags.removeAll { $0 == tag }
                    }
                }
                
                // Manage Tags Button
                Button(action: { showingTagManagement = true }) {
                    Text("Manage")
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingTagManagement) {
                testView(tags: $tags)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TagView: View {
    let tag: String
    let onDelete: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            Text(tag)
            Button(action: onDelete) {
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct testView: View {
    @Binding var tags: [String]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
            Text(tag)
        }
        Button("test") {
            tags.append("test")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



Congrats on the asking again the most asked question on here

I found a solution to the problem, which lies in the fact that when I clicked on the Manage button, I noticed that the click event would cover the entire VStack in the Form.
So every time I clicked on the Manage button, I actually clicked on all the delete buttons in the TagView. It clears the tags.
To fix it, I simply added .buttonstyle (.plain) under the Manage and delete buttons
Button(action: { showingTagManagement = true }) {
    Text("Manage")
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)

Button("test") {
    tags.append("test")
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)

